# Target Android 2.1

Tags: android, eclipse, api, sdk, target

I want to execute a HelloWorld project with Android using eclipse Juno, but when I run the project I always obtain this result:

```
 [2014-10-28 18:37:07 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
 [2014-10-28 18:37:07 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
 [2014-10-28 18:37:07 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
 [2014-10-28 18:37:07 - HelloWorld] Performing com.javacodegeeks.android.helloword.MainActivity activity launch
 [2014-10-28 18:37:08 - HelloWorld] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 2.1'.
 [2014-10-28 18:37:13 - HelloWorld] Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Android 2.1': Aborting launch.
 [2014-10-28 18:37:13 - HelloWorld] Performing com.javacodegeeks.android.helloword.MainActivity activity launch
 [2014-10-28 18:37:16 - HelloWorld] Launch canceled!$
```

Comment: `Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 2.1'.` Do you have the emulator properly set up?

Comment: Your emulator ins't running Android 2.1. Have you checked your Emulator Android version?

Comment: My android virtual device is Androir 2.1 API 7

Answer (score 0):

it was a problem with the project, it asks at minimum an emulator with API 15 at least whiel i was using Android 2.1 API7